# ElasticSearch terms aggregation on tokenized field

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

when i do terms aggregation on string field (with whitespace tokenizer) i have results for each word (token), but i need results for whole strings. 
How can i do aggregation on string field like terms but group output by whole string, not by tokens?

I already saw this solutions: 
[ElasticSearch term aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769366/elasticsearch-term-aggregation)
[Terms aggregation based on unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484789/terms-aggregation-based-on-unique-key)
but they are based on keyword tokenizer

I can't use keyword tokenizer, because of i wan't apply stopwords filter while indexing

Comment: Post what you already tried (mapping, queries, data samples, expectations).

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem, and came here looking for a solution.

And then it dawned on me. there's a .raw (unanalyzed) field, and it worked. The solution was to use it.

So the aggregation went from:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "keys": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 0,
        "field": "key"
}}}}}
```

to:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "keys": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 0,
        "field": "key.raw"
}}}}}
```

Comment: This works only if you have set the fields as raw field.

Comment: Which, at least in the version of ELK stack that I'm running, is the default.

Comment: it worked for me without key.raw, I had to recreate the index, I guess my mapping was not defined earlier. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is a bit confusing -- why you would need the .raw is that there might be keys broken up when analyzed. In my case, they are formatted "AAAA-BBB-CCC" . I am not able to query for them key using the analyzed field, but .raw does the trick.